# Regex to match all character groups in a string

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match the groups of characters in a string.
For example `this is-a@beautiful^day`.
Should result in the following list: `this`, `is`, `a`, `beautiful`, `day`.
As a mention I don't know how long the string is or by what characters the words are separated.

Any ideas? I have no clue how to build a regex for this.

Comment: So you want to split the string using any character which is not a letter? (What about digits?)

Comment: Have you [read the docs?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: no digits included, only letters sepparated by any other characters except digits

Comment: You do not need `regex` for that. You could simply do: `''.join(x if x.isalpha() else ' ' for x in s).split()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want find all groups of letters:

```
import re

string = "this is-a@beautiful^day"
list = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+', string)
print list

['this', 'is', 'a', 'beautiful', 'day']
```